# Variable in constructor in external JS file in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby

Scenario:

- Code below is in an external JS file (loaded from a CDN)
- User is on page 1 where this file is included
- User then navigates to page 2 where this file is also included

Is it true that on page 2 `this.url` will still have the URL value of page 1 because of how Gatsby works? I'm not familiar with it hence the question.

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.url = window.location.href;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gatsby (because it extends from `@reach/router`) exposes a default `prop` named `location` in all pages with all the information that you are requesting in your answer. You can handle this `prop` and pass it to the childs components and use it like you wish.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
const Page = ({ location }) => {
  console.log(location)
  return <div>The URL of this page is {canonicalUrl}</div>
}
export default Page
```

Check [Location Data from Props](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) for detailed information.

If your constructor is called in both pages your `this.url` will be updated with `window.location.href` because it will be triggered in each page. Keep in mind the differences between using an anchor (`<a>`) or the `@reach/router` from React (`<Link`).

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to add this to the question, but this external JS file is one that lives on many other (non-Gatsby) websites as well. So I'd like to explore a solution that's pure JS and works in all Gatsby and non-Gatsby websites.

Comment: If your constructor is called in both pages your `this.url` will be updated with `window.location.href` because it will be triggered in each page. Keep in mind the differences between using an anchor (`<a>`) or the `@reach/router` from React (`<Link`)